# Is it possibile to have python PyDoc module to return a string with the content instead of just printing it?

Tags: python, pydoc

The function `pydoc.doc()` returns `None`, but i would like to capture the output the function prints, how can i do that using python code?

Comment: Are you trying to get the docstring of a specific method / class / function? Something else?

Comment: Yeah, for example: pydoc.doc('math.cos') shows the help for the .cos() function but just returns None.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pydoc.doc` has `output` parameter which should be something supporting `.write`, you can use `io.StringIO` for that purpose following way:

```
import io
import pydoc
f = io.StringIO()
pydoc.doc(object, output=f)
f.seek(0)
objectdoc = f.read()
print(type(objectdoc))
print(objectdoc)
```

Output:

```
<class 'str'>
Python Library Documentation: class object in module builtins

class object
 |  The most base type
```

Note that `io.StringIO` behaves generally just like file, but is not saved on disk (=is not persistent). I used `object` as example as its documentation is short.

Answer (score 0):

Create a text buffer for output option of pydoc.doc

```py
import pydoc
from io import StringIO

buffer = StringIO()
pydoc.doc('math.cos', output=buffer)
text = buffer.getvalue()
```